# How to clear MutableLiveData<List<String>> in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I create `ViewModel` with `MutableLiveData<List<String>>`.

And I need to remove all items from it.

So I use clear function as below.

```
   class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
        var regionModelData = MutableLiveData<List<String>>()
        var regionDataList = regionModelData.value
        var templateList = mutableListOf<String>()

        fun addRegion(text: String) {
            regionDataList?.forEach { data ->
                templateList.add(data.toString())
            }
            templateList.add(text)
            regionModelData.value = templateList
        }

        fun clearRegion() {
            regionModelData.value = emptyList()
        }
    }
```

And I call clearRegion function before addRegion().

```
        var regionRegister: BroadcastReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
            override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
                regionModel.clearRegion()

                var changeRegion = intent!!.getStringExtra("selectedRegion").toString()

                Log.d("지역확인", "${changeRegion}")

                regionDB
                    .document("4ggk4cR82mz46CjrLg60")
                    .collection("small_region")
                    .document(changeRegion)
                    .get()
                    .addOnSuccessListener { documents ->

                        documents.data?.forEach { (k, v) ->
                            regionModel.addRegion(v.toString())
                        }
                        Log.d("리지온", "${documents.data}", )
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                    }

            }
        }
```

But `regionModelData` keeps being added, not cleared at all.

How can I clear all items of list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have two different properties tracking the same data (`regionModelData` and `regionDataList`). `regionDataList` is not going to automatically follow whatever the value is that's set inside the LiveData. You should just eliminate this property.

You are "clearing" the `regionDataList` by replacing it with a new empty list in the ViewModel, but other classes that reference the original List don't know anything about that `var` property and are still referencing the original instance.

You should remove `regionDataList` and `templateList`, and update the adapter in an `observe` call on your LiveData, so it always gets notified of the latest value.

Your `addRegion` function can be revised as follows:

```
    fun addRegion(text: String) {
        regionModelData.value = regionModelData.value + text
    }
```

Comment: I just realized you are sort of doing both 1 and 3. You just need to eliminate the `regionDataList` property and exclusively update your adapter in an observer of the LiveData. I revised the answer.

Comment: But your adding way is not working. before I asked similar question, and I got current code answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75022794/how-to-use-mutablelivedataliststring-as-data-of-recyclerview-adapter

Comment: But your point was really helpful. I solve the problem by clearing all three variables